# Getting Response of Type cors on web api .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm just trying to return a url to a client i already did all configuration of cors policy but the only return i recieve is of type cors, without any signal of the url that i want to return, the preflight request works fine and the request itself either, the return of my api its my problem.

this is my startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddTransient<ITokenManager, TokenManager>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddSingleton<IAccountService, AccountService>();
            services.AddSingleton<ITableauService, TableauService>();


            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .Build();

                    });
            });

            services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowAll"));
            });

            services.AddMvc();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCors("AllowAll");
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
        }
    }
```

fetch api request from client

```
  fetch('https://baseurl?folder=AcompanhamentoComparativoLocaliza&view=DashEmails'
            , {

                headers: new Headers({
                    'authorization': 'AuthToken',
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',

                })
            })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('teste',response)


                }
                )
                .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

[this is the output of cors policy, as you guys can see they are executed sucessfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8cYY.png)

[this is the return in my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQtf9.png)

and now the network in my client

[preflight network headers and status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbJAz.png)

[Request itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szqdT.png)

[response from the api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWQrj.png)

Thanks in advance, i apreaciate any help.

Comment: In network tab, have you checked the response body for your API call? Also, share client code for calling? If you are using `jquery.ajax` trying setting up `dataType: "text"`

Comment: Ok i will update the question with the example of request, im using fetch api, thanks for your time mohsin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response type is `cors` means

> Response was received from a valid cross-origin request. Certain headers and the body may be accessed.

So just get the returned data using :

```
.then(response => {
  response.json().then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
)
```

In addition , if you want to return url , you should add double quotes ,for example :

```
return Content("\"https://localhost:8080\"");
```